Python filtering and extract text
I am pretty new to coding and lately I chanced upon something which I wanted to try solving with Python. Below is the text content of which I wanted to query, extract certain fields into a new file. The text content is repetitive and can go up to several thousands of line. Currently, I am only able to parse and output the first two columns which still look wrong. Hope to seek some guidance here. Cheers!
Original TXT File:
Classroom arrangement : 1A-1
    (Student Name: Jess, Subject: EC001, Time: 9am - 10am)
    (Student Name: Whit, Subject: EC001, Time: 9am - 10am)
    (Student Name: Jon, Subject: EC0011, Time: 11am - 12pm)
    (Student Name: Kevin, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm)
    (Student Name: Jess, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm)
Classroom arrangement : 1A-2
    (Student Name: Jess, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
    (Student Name: Whit, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
    (Student Name: Jon, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
    (Student Name: Kevin, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
    (Student Name: Claire, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm)
    (Student Name: Joshua, Subject: EC0011, Time: 2pm - 3pm)
    (Student Name: Florence, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm)
    (Student Name: Neil, Subject: EC011, Time: 2am - 3pm)
Intended Output:
Classroom: 1A-1, Jess, Subject: EC001 Time: 9am - 10am, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-1, Whit, Subject: EC001 Time: 9am - 10am
Classroom: 1A-1, Jon, Subject: EC0011 Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-1, Kevin, Subject: EC011 Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Jess, Subject: EC002 Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Jon, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Whit, Subject: EC002 Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Kevin, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Claire, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Joshua, Subject: EC0011, Time: 2pm - 3pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Florence, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Neil, Subject: EC011, Time: 2am - 3pm
I tried passing readlines into modules before performing an output in the console, but it seems really wrong because I need the Class 1A-1 preceding on each line.
Current Output:
Class 1A-1
Jess, Subject: EC001 Time: 9am - 10am 
Jess, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm
Whit, Subject: EC001 Time: 9am - 10am
Jon, Subject: EC0011 Time: 11am - 12pm
Kevin, Subject: EC011 Time: 11am - 12pm

Do you really need to use pandas?

i am not sure mozway.. i just think some part of my logic process could be wrong... thus i thought of asking for some guidance here..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please add the Python code so that you can receive assistance.

Here's your solution. You'll need to tweak the values for the input/output filepaths:
classroom.py
import collections


def ingest(infilepath):
    """
    Read all the input from the input file.
    Store it in a dictionary so that we can parse it out later.
    We'll use a collections.defaultdict to make life easier
        {classroom name: {student name: [classes...]} }
            key'd by student name since a student can have multiple courses in a classroom
    """
    answer = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        classes = infile.read().split('\n\n')  # divide the input into blocks of classrooms
        classes = [c.strip() for c in classes]  # strip out any extra whitespace

    for classblock in classes:
        name, *records = classblock.splitlines()  # student records per classroom
        name = name.split(':',1)[-1].strip()
        for record in records:
            record = record.replace("(", "").replace(")", '')  # strip out the "()". We don't need that
            kvs = record.split(',')

            d = dict(kv.split(":") for kv in kvs)
            d = {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in d.items()}

            answer[name][d['Student Name']].append(d)

    return answer


def output(outfilepath, data):
    order = ("Subject", "Time")  # the order in which we want to write the output
    with open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for classname, d in data.items():
            for studentname, L in d.items():
                outfile.write(f"Classroom: {classname}, {studentname}, ")
                out = []  # maintain the line output in a list. We'll join everything up later
                for d in L:
                    for k in order:
                        out.append(f"{k}: {d[k]}, ")

                out = ''.join(out)  # this is the file output
                out = out.strip().rstrip(',')  # strip out the trailing ','
                outfile.write(f'{out}\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('starting')

    data = ingest('path/to/input/file')
    output('path/to/output/file', data)

    print('done')

I used this input (notice the blank lines at the start of the file):


Classroom arrangement : 2A-1
(Student Name: Jess, Subject: EC001, Time: 9am - 10am)
(Student Name: Whit, Subject: EC001, Time: 9am - 10am)
(Student Name: Jon, Subject: EC0011, Time: 11am - 12pm)
(Student Name: Kevin, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm)
(Student Name: Jess, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm)


Classroom arrangement : 1A-2
(Student Name: Jess, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
(Student Name: Whit, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
(Student Name: Jon, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
(Student Name: Kevin, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm)
(Student Name: Claire, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm)
(Student Name: Joshua, Subject: EC0011, Time: 2pm - 3pm)
(Student Name: Florence, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm)
(Student Name: Neil, Subject: EC011, Time: 2am - 3pm)

I got this output:
Classroom: 1A-1, Jess, Subject: EC001, Time: 9am - 10am, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-1, Whit, Subject: EC001, Time: 9am - 10am
Classroom: 1A-1, Jon, Subject: EC0011, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-1, Kevin, Subject: EC011, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Jess, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Whit, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Jon, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Kevin, Subject: EC002, Time: 11am - 12pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Claire, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Joshua, Subject: EC0011, Time: 2pm - 3pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Florence, Subject: EC011, Time: 2pm - 3pm
Classroom: 1A-2, Neil, Subject: EC011, Time: 2am - 3pm

Hope this helps

Thank you for your guidance!! Appreciate it :)
